# NSUserDefault with App Group is not working in iOS 8 Beta3

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

I have to save `Boolean` Value to `NSUserDefault` in my App with `custom keyboard extension` and share with App Group.

My Code is worked in `iOS 8` Beta1.

```
self.defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([self.defaults boolForKey:@"BlackKey"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Black");
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"White");
    }
```

But Not in iOS 8 Beta3. When i retrieve `Boolean` value from `NSUserDefault` , it's return nothing and i can't load from custom keyboard extension.

I have also tried with `initWithSuiteName` in `NSUserDefault`. Am i only one for that problem or bugs of iOS 8 Beta3?

Answer (score 2):

A few probable solutions are:

1. Your app group is not setup correctly, or you are not using the correct group identifier with `initWithSuiteName:`
2. You have not enabled network access for your keyboard. [This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1) states the following when you have network access disabled for your keyboard (default behavior):

   > No shared container with containing app
3. It's a bug.

Comment: So you mean , i have to enable RequestsOpenAccess to use NSUserDefault?

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in beta 5

Answer (score -5):

Try using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"BlackKey"];
```

when you save and read it by using this code:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"BlackKey"]) {
    NSLog(@"Black");
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"White");
}
```

or if you already done so, then it can be bug, and Xcode 6 beta versions also have other bugs so it's safer to try in Xcode 5 or older.

Comment: It's not work. You should say iOS 8 Beta and iOS7. Not XCode 8 Beta. :D